# Mootools - tween or morph effects at the same time

Tags: javascript, mootools

Is there a way to trigger two morph or tween effects for two different dom elements at the exact same time?

I created this demo. http://jsfiddle.net/jLmAS/ Click the green block to test.

It seems to work alright although it doesn't seem technically correct. I can imagine if there were 1000 blocks you would see a lag with the bottom blocks.

Any thoughts or ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what the animation does is the same on both elements, there's no reason for using `morph` and `tween`. Otherwise, what you're looking for is `Fx.Elements` (http://mootools.net/docs/more/Fx/Fx.Elements), it takes an Element Collection and applies different animations to them. `Fx.Elements` is there for the sole reason of animating multiple elements at the same time.

Comment: Btw. `document.id('block-1')` > `$$('#block-1');` - getting an Element Collection and then extracting a selector is slower, than just fetching the element by ID.